Odoo: Outdated term is keeping on DB when translations terms on a related field if value changes
I have a field that is related to a translate = True, but when value changes from a form, it only changes the translated term. Old term is being keep on DB.
Let's say we have this model A:
class Main(models.Model):
 name = fields.Char(translate=True)

class Child(models.Model):
 parent_id = fields.Many2one('main')
 parent_name = fields.Char(related='parent_id.name', store=True)

When a record is created, lets say that child have 'open' (id 1) value on DB. PSQL:
parent_id | parent_name

1         |  {'en_GB': 'open'}

Now supposed an spanish user, changes it to won (Ganado in spanish), id 2. PSQL:
parent_id | parent_name

2         | {'en_GB': 'open', 'es_ES': 'ganado'}

When a english user see the record, it gets foo. But spanish user was OK. So changes on DB only updating the term from the frontend instead of syncronization with the comodel.
I debugged the code but value is getting from is the translated term from the frontend ('bar').
PSQL line is
UPDATE "child" SET "parent_name" = '{"en_GB": "won"}' || COALESCE("parent_name", '{}'::jsonb) || '{"es_ES": "ganado"}' 
but that COALESCE sentence is preventing old value to be overriding

Sorry it's bit difficult to understand. You mean the parent record's translation is NOT updated when the related field's translation in the child record gets another translation? That's seems like a bug to me.

hey Cris @CZoellner , the parent is ok, the issue is strictly on DB. Once a user that's not using english, it updates only its language term but old value term is present. So when an english user retrieves the value, it's shows the old value (en)
These are the values stored on DB:
Before:

{"en_US": "Open"}

After (ES user changes value to Won)

{"en_US": "Open", "es_ES": "Ganado"}  -- EN user sees Open, ES user sees Won

So it's a bug, I'm surprised I'm the first person on reporting it: Maybe bcst I found very fews related, stored and translated fields.

When the spanish user (with Spanish as active language) just changes the value (form view) only the spanish translation will be changed. That's normal. Or do you meant the spanish user is changing both language's values at once?

That's normal. But when an english user sees the record, since the english term was not updated, it sees a wrong value. So its like terms aren't being synchronized. ES user sees  value while EN user sees  value.

I think we're talking past each other. Changing the value in one language never changes other language's values. Except when using the translate-Feature in the UI.

If helps, I have a workaround to handle related and translated fields. I don't like so much but works.
from odoo import fields, models, api
from odoo.models import LOG_ACCESS_COLUMNS
from psycopg2.extras import Json


class TranslateRelatedField(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'translate.related.field'

    """
    override of models._write to fully override translations when value changes
    eg.: have a stored related field to crm.stage::name
    stage_id: 1
    stage_name: {'en_US': 'open'}
    when a spanish user changes value to 2 (won),
    stage_id: 2
    stage_name: {'en_US': 'open', 'es_ES': 'ganado'} -- won
    the stored related field remains the older english value (open)
    """

    def _write(self, vals):
        """ Low-level implementation of write()

        The ids of self should be a database id and unique.
        Ignore non-existent record.
        """
        if not self:
            return

        cr = self._cr

        # determine records that require updating parent_path
        parent_records = self._parent_store_update_prepare(vals)

        if self._log_access:
            # set magic fields (already done by write(), but not for computed fields)
            vals = dict(vals)
            vals.setdefault('write_uid', self.env.uid)
            vals.setdefault('write_date', self.env.cr.now())

        # determine SQL values
        columns = []
        params = []

        for name, val in sorted(vals.items()):
            if self._log_access and name in LOG_ACCESS_COLUMNS and not val:
                continue
            field = self._fields[name]
            assert field.store
            assert field.column_type
            if field.translate is True and val:
                if field.related:  # override
                    columns.append(f'''"{name}" =  %s ''')
                    en_US_value = eval('self.' + field.related)  # extract original value
                    terms = {'en_US': en_US_value}
                    terms.update(val.adapted)  # update if other language term is coming
                    params.append(Json(terms))
                else:
                    columns.append(f'''"{name}" = %s || COALESCE("{name}", '{{}}'::jsonb) || %s''')
                    params.append(Json({} if 'en_US' in val.adapted else {'en_US': next(iter(val.adapted.values()))}))
                    params.append(val)
            else:
                columns.append(f'"{name}" = %s')
                params.append(val)

        # update columns
        if columns:
            template = ', '.join(columns)
            query = f'UPDATE "{self._table}" SET {template} WHERE id IN %s'
            for sub_ids in cr.split_for_in_conditions(self._ids):
                cr.execute(query, params + [sub_ids])

        # update parent_path
        if parent_records:
            parent_records._parent_store_update()

